# Can't install Mayavi on Anaconda distribution

Tags: manjaro, python3

Ok, I am not really sure if this is the right place to post such question, so if it is not, please, tell me where it is more adequate.

My problem: I just move from Ubuntu 19.04 to Manjaro 18. I have some graphical python 3 programs that used to work pretty fine on Ubuntu, but now, I just can't run then into Manjaro. The main problem is that I can't install [Mayavi](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/) with Anaconda distribution. I tried

```
pip install mayavi
```

And I get:

```
Command "/home/us/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-7noyncgf/traits/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-p80x70yv/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-7noyncgf/traits/
```

Is there anything I can do to solve this?

Comment: What release of Anaconda are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always found that when installing Mayavi with Anaconda, it's best to use `conda` rather than `pip` no matter the distribution. This will install it via the Anaconda repos.

```
conda install -c anaconda mayavi
```

That's assuming you have the `bin` directory of Anaconda prepended to your path. The  `-c anaconda` switch tells it to install Mayavi from the Anaconda repo. The installation will also be successful with

```
conda install mayavi
```

I simply prefer the first but it's up to you. It will install Mayavi and it will be usable just the same.

Afterwards, you can see it installed with any of the following commands:

```
conda list | grep mayavi
pip list | grep mayavi
pip freeze | grep mayavi
```